Independence of random variables on $\mathbb{R}^d$
Cohn's measure theory book states the following:

I do not understand why $X_1$ and $X_2$ exist. I do understand if $d=1$.
He has built in a previous section independent borelian random variables $Y_1,Y_2:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which are uniformly distributed. Then, with a clever monotone function ( hence borel measurable), we are able to build: $X_1=F_{\nu_1}^{-1}\circ Y_1$ and $X_2=F_{v_2}^{-1}\circ Y_2$ which satisfy:
$$\nu_j(A)=\lambda X^{-1}_j(A)$$
Where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$. Clearly $\sigma (X_1)\subseteq \sigma(Y_1)$ and $\sigma (X_2)\subseteq \sigma(Y_2)$ and because $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also independent.
This would work if $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ were borelian measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Is this easily generalizable in the context of borelian measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which Cohn uses in this proposition? I searched a bit online and stumbled upon Kolmogorov’s existence theorem, but I think this isn't exactly what I am looking for as $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ appears. If Kolmogorov does do the trick could someone apply it in this more pedestrian context?

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for since it does not proof the existence of $X_1$ and $X_2$, but you can construct them in a similar way as described by you (you describe the quantile transformation). The multivariate version of this is the Rosenblatt transformation. Maybe looking it up will help you.

I can give you two positive answers:

The first one is trivial if you do not care about the underlying probability space.
The second one is interesting because it does not require to change the probability space as long as it is wide enough to define at least a uniform random variable. However the proof is more technical.

They both rely on the following fact: the existence of a random variable $X_1$ following $\nu_1$ independent of a random variable $X_2$ following $\nu_2$ is equivalent to the existence of a random variable $X$ following the product measure $\nu_1\otimes\nu_2$. This equivalence is easily deduced from the definition of the product measure.
So we just need to prove the existence of such $X\sim\nu_1\otimes\nu_2$.
First method: very simple but no flexibility on the probability space
Let $\Omega=\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d$ be endowed with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ and the probability measure $\nu_1\otimes\nu_2$ itself. Then $\Omega$ is a probability space, and the random variable
$$
X:\begin{array}{rcl}\Omega&\to&\mathbb R^{d}\times\mathbb R^d\\\omega&\mapsto&\omega\end{array}
$$
follows $\nu_1\otimes\nu_2$.
Second method: more technical but more general
As $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)=\mathcal B(\mathbb R^{2d})$, the measurable space $E=(\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$ is a Polish space endowed with its Borel $\sigma$-field. Therefore, $E$ is a Borel space, that is it is Borel isomorphic to a Borel set in $[0,1]$. This fact can be found for instance as Theorem 1.8 of Kallenberg's book, Foundations of Modern Probability, 3rd Edition, 2021. As a consequence, there exists a measurable map $h:(0,1)\to E$ such that $\nu_1\otimes\nu_2$ is the image of the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$ by $h$. In other words, if $U$ is a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$, then $X=h(U)\sim\nu_1\otimes\nu_2$.
Note that this time, $X$ is defined on the same probability space as $U$. So the existence of such a random variable $X$ holds for any underlying probability space wide enough to contain a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$.
Remark: the hard part is to show that $E$ is a Borel space. In other words, there exists a bijective measurable map $\varphi:\mathbb R\to E$ such that $\varphi^{-1}$ is measurable. Once you get there, just show the statement in $\mathbb R$, and extend it to $E$ thanks to the use of $\varphi$.

When $X$ is the identity it seems that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ the projection of $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ seem to do the trick as $X_1$ and $X_2$, because $$\nu_1\otimes\nu_2(\pi_1^{-1}(A_1)\cap \pi_2^{-1}(A_2))=\nu_1\otimes\nu_2(A_1\times A_2)=\nu_1(A_1)\nu_2(A_2)=$$$$\nu_1\otimes\nu_2(\pi_1^{-1}(A_1))\nu_1\otimes\nu_2( \pi_2^{-1}(A_2))$$ Also:$$\nu_1\times\nu_2(\pi_1^{-1}(A_1))=\nu_1(A_1)$$ For a general $X$ in the first method I was not able to prove $\pi_1\circ X$ and $\pi_2\circ X$ satisfy similar properties. I am very new to this! Could you help me a little bit more?

Anyways $X$ being the identity already serves very well for this particular case in Cohn's Theorem. Thank you so much for such a rich answer. It made me want to really learn more about analytic/polish spaces this summer. :)

I am not sure to see what your question is about $\pi_1\circ X$ and $\pi_2\circ X$. You have that $\mathbb P(\pi_1\circ X\in A)=(\nu_1\otimes\nu_2)(X\in\pi_1^{-1}(A))=(\nu_1\otimes\nu_2)(A\times\mathbb R^d)=\nu_1(A)$. So $\pi_1\circ X$ follows $\nu_1$. Was that your question?

Ow $X$ follows $\nu_1\otimes \nu_2$. Makes complete sense. Sorry! Completely clear now.
